# Android Camera Button Half Way Pressed Listener

Tags: android, button, camera, listener, autofocus

I am building a custom camera app and have got the basics to work. I have also been able to block the camera button from initializing the real camera app. The only thing that I would like to do is build in autofocus when the camera button is half pressed.

I am comfortable using `camera.autofocus`, but cannot find a way to listen for the camera button to be halfway pressed (like the default camera app does) to start the autofocus call.

Is there a keycode or another way to listen for the camera button being depressed to its half way point?

Comment: It is probably specific to your manufacturer.  I don't think I've seen it on anything other than Motorola devices.

Comment: @Mr.Zander- I have seen 3rd party apps use this feature to autofocus the camera. I guess how do they pull it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a little creative and just toasted any key down event in android. I ended up finding out that the key code for camera focus is 80 this way. This also matches up with the android documentation once I knew what I was looking for.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {


    if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

        Toast.makeText(this, new Integer(keyCode).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Hope this helps others.

Comment: Just to clarify, the key code is [KEYCODE_FOCUS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_FOCUS).

Answer (score -1):

The camera button is a virtual button on the screen, I am not sure how it can the half pressed, or even could be mimicked in any way.

Comment: On the Droid-X there is an actual button and on other phones it is there as well. This button has a half position like a real camera that triggers the camera to autofocus. This may be being phased out with API 14 and later that allows continuous autofocus, but there are still plenty of devices that require it.